# Update Laravel model from external API

Tags: laravel

I have a `Coin` model with `id,name,price`.

In a function, I extract all the coins and create a comma separated string with all the ids:

```
$coins = Coin::all();
$coinsIds = $coins->pluck('id')->toArray();
$coinsIdsString = implode(',', $coinsIds);
```

After that I make a call to an external API:

```
$url = 'https://myapi.com?ids' . $coinsIdsString;
$response = Http::get($url)->json();
```

`$response` value is an array of coins, something like:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"A",
      "price":"1.2",
   },
   ...
]
```

What would be the best way to update and save my Coin model with the `price` value from API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to do anything other than update a single record at a time. That is, loop through the results of the array and perform a database update on each record. My recommendation is

```
$results = ... // Result of API call;

foreach ($results as $result) {
   DB::table('coins')
      ->where('id', $result['id'])
      ->update(['price' => $result['price']]);
}
```

I would then create a scheduled command to periodically perform the update since it is likely to be resource intensive depending on the volume of calls.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I thought. Already created a job https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues and scheduled it https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs.
Do you think artisan commands would be more appropriate than scheduling queued jobs?

Comment: It depends on the circumstances you want the price import to happen. Want them imported each night? Use a scheduled command. Want them to import based on user action? Use a queue.

Comment: Also, probably no need to use Coin::all() as it pulls in unused fields. Just use Coin::select('id')->get()->pluck('id')->toArray()

Comment: I need to import each minute not based on user actions but i don't get it. Why would it be better to use an artisan command instead of a job?